# [sprig]-tag: remove from some questions + rename it

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Today, I have checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56769515/picked-up-java-options-djava-net-preferipv4stack-true) and I noticed a possible incorrect tag: [sprig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sprig). I was curious about that and there are only [six questions with the said tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sprig). I assumed that it is a result of a typo, that the tag creator meant [spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring). But apparently that is a function template library for Go: http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/ So some questions got tagged incorrectly.

I am not sure what to do with the tag. I thought to remove it at first, but after I found out that it is used in Go, an other approach has to be taken.

So far, I think that two actions has to be done;

1. Remove (or replace it with Spring's one) that tag from java based question
2. Add description to the tag and rename it to `sprig-template` to prevent further mis-use in the future.

Or should something else happen?

Answer (score 3):

Action 1. seemed to be taken care of already by someone. I completed 2.

I renamed the tag from [sprig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sprig) to [sprig-template-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sprig-template-functions) because the GitHub documentation mentions:

> sprig - Useful template functions for Go templates.

The name can still be changed if any expert in that field lets us know of a better tag. The next task now is to create a meaningful tag wiki for that tag.